# удалить избыточную точность в определении местоположения

Tags: python, geopy

еще раз)
переформатировала задачу, теперь
я использую geopandas, Geopy(from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim)

```
import geopy
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim


test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="check")

test["address"] = test.apply(lambda row: (geolocator.reverse(str(row.latitude) + ',' + str(row.longitude))).address, axis=1)

test.head(5)
```

и вот что получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

есть какой-то способ сократить местоположения до "Россия, Москва"

спасибо

Comment: А что это вообще, в каком виде то данные? `csv`, `json`, ещё что-то?

Comment: координаты объекта в москве? опасно. Но тут такое дело, одну цифру в 6 разряде после запятой убираем и точность начинает гулять на метр в 5 - на десятки метров. 1 градус по меридиану это чуть больше 100 км.

Comment: KoVadim,
а по Питеру тоже самое? есть координаты, типа 59.912 30.348, почему то определяется как Ленинградская область (в OSM), но по Nominatim определяется как Питер

Comment: меридиан он везде меридиан. Я посмотрел на координаты указанных целей. Они прям так на границе города. И тут одна цифра в пятом разряде после запятой и все, уже в другом месте. Так что ожидаемо. когда координаты указываются так, как Вы пишите, то тут может быть два трактования - как доли градуса, так и две цифры минуты, потом две цифры секунды и десятые -сотые секунды. И погрешность при такой ошибке - десятки клилометров

Comment: KoVadim
а это даже и не цели, это полигоны с Osm boundaries. И у меня есть файл с координатами, к примеру (59.912 30.348)  и мне нужно узнать входит ли точка в тот или иной полигон для определения положения. я поняла, что очень много нюансов, питон хорошо решает вопрос с Nominatim, но моя задача сделать некий справочник полигонов в БД.

Comment: @Archi Так а зачем вам нужно сокращать число знаков? Для определения вхождения это же не нужно

Comment: для определения вхождения это даже вредно.

Comment: Приведите данные в воспроизводимом виде. И код такой, чтобы там все нужные импорты и создания объектов были, к которым вы обращаетесь. Токены если какие есть, их скройте, а остальное всё нужно.

Comment: Здесь посмотрите, там можно же не только `address` целиком брать, но и другие всякие штуки https://stackoverflow.com/a/40476209/8324991

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 36.35234563235

# round(число, количество цифр после запятой)
a = round(a, 1)
```